# Drupal custom form and autocomplete issue

Tags: autocomplete, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-forms

Some how I managed to get it work. But still the result is not coming along with the autocomplete.

Posting my latest code now,

the textfield code

```
$form['town'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#autocomplete_path' => 'hfind/town/autocomplete',
);
```

menu function code

```
function hfind_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['hfind/town/autocomplete'] = array (
    'title' => 'Autocomplete for cities',
    'page callback' => 'hfind_town_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('use autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
   );
return $items;
}
```

the callback function code

```
function hfind_town_autocomplete($string){
  $matches = array();
  $result = db_select('towns', 't')
    ->fields('t', array('town_name'))
    ->condition('town_name', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $matches[$row->city] = check_plain($row->city);
  }
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

I hope this may the final edit.

The current situation is, autocomplete is working

The url is hfind/town/autocomplete/mtw

but it is not able to find any data from the database. I found why and unable to fix it. 
It is because in the last function I've added above the $string needs to be the 'search query' but it is always querying the database as 'autocomplete'. I mean the $string variable always having the value 'autocomplete' instead of user typed value.

One more problem is, even after providing the permission to all types of user to access search autocomplete on the forms, guests users are not able to use the feature.

Please please someone help me..

Answer (score 0):

```
`drupal_json_output()` instead of `drupal_to_js` and remove `print` .
<code>
hook_menu() {
$items['cnetusers/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Auto complete path',
    'page callback' => 'cnetusers_employees_autocomplete',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4, 5),
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
return $item;
}
// my autocomplete function is like this
function cnetusers_employees_autocomplete() {
  // write your sql query
    $matches["$record->ename $record->elname [id: $record->uid]"] = $value;
  }
  if (empty($matches)) {
    $matches[''] = t('No matching records found.');
  }
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}

$form['disc_info']['approval'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Approval By'),
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'cnetusers/autocomplete',
    );
</code>
```

Comment: I tried. Still not working. But I know this fix is not really for my problem because when I type I can't see any request with the text. The autocomplete feature is not active with the text field.

Comment: try to check the path for tht autocomplete function which you gave.
i have edited my answer with one small example  and tht work for me.

Comment: Thanks Ranjeet, tried and trying lot of solutions, nothing working.

Comment: Can you show your recent code which you are trying for autocomplete.
I am asking because the code which i posted is very simple and always work for me.